# How to parse application log without order and structure using Grok

Tags: aws-glue, grok

I'm parsing application log using Grok, testing with https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match.

The log presents like below:

```
2023-04-01 02:00:00,007 [nioEventLoopGroup-13-13] INFO {"deviceid":"aaaaaaaaaa","userAgent":"device"}
2023-04-01 02:00:01,234 [nioEventLoopGroup-13-13] INFO {"userAgent":"device","deviceid":"bbbbbbbbbb"}
2023-04-01 02:00:02,234 [nioEventLoopGroup-13-13] INFO {"userAgent":"device"}
```

My Grok pattern:

```
%{GENERATE_TIME:generateTime}.*?%{DEVICEID:deviceId}.*?%{AGENT:userAgent}
```

Custom pattern:

```
GENERATE_TIME \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}
DEVICEID deviceid":"(.{10})
AGENT "userAgent":"(.*?)"
```

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOkZf.png)

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
        "generateTime": "2023-04-01·02:00:00,007",
        "deviceId": "aaaaaaaaaa",
        "userAgent": "device"
    },
    {
        "generateTime": "2023-04-01·02:00:01,234",
        "deviceId": "bbbbbbbbbb",
        "userAgent": "device"
    },
    {
        "generateTime": "2023-04-01·02:00:02,234",
        "userAgent": "device"
    }
]
```

It seems that there are two problems to solve, how to match `deviceId` and `userAgent` cleanly, how to parse log without order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the below grok pattern and feedback?

```
filter
{
grok
{
match => 
{
"message" => ['%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:event}] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:deviceid}:%{DATA:id},%{DATA:useragent}:"%{DATA:agentname}"
', '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:event}] %{DATA:loglevel} %{DATA:useragent}:"%{DATA:agentname}"']
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works more properly. The first two lines are parsed sucessfully, but the last not. I finally decided to write a ETL program. Before AWS Glue crawling logs, the program extracts them.

Comment: I have also changed the pattern for the last line as well. Hope it might help in case. Good luck.

Comment: IMHO, to match the Log Level, the recommendation is to use %{LOGLEVEL} instead of %{DATA}. Thus, `%{DATA:loglevel}` should be %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}

Comment: Thanks for the pointing it out. Modified the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below `grok` pattern:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:generateTime} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:json_data}" }
}
```

This should match all 3 lines above. And in order to get the output you specified, just after `grok`, you can use

```
json {
  source => "json_data"
  remove_field => ["json_data"]
}
```

The `json` filter will parse the `json_data` into individual fields.